# Using Angular 4 how do I make a http promise call inside of an observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, observable, aws-api-gateway

Using Angular 4 how do I make a http promise call inside of an Observable?  I am using AWS API Gateway with Cognito Federated accounts. We have to use the apigClient.invokeApi to sign each http call. I want to get the results of promise call and return the result as an observable. The code below fires but does not get to the rest of the observable code at all. When I subscribe to the observable it never gets to the code inside of the subscribe. I am not getting any compile errors either. Any help would be helpful.

```
public upload(image, fileType): Observable<FileReturnData> {
  const apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    accessKey: this.auth.cognitoAccessKey,
    secretKey: this.auth.cognitoSecretKey,
    sessionToken: this.auth.cognitoSessionToken,
    invokeUrl: this.auth.URL
  });
  const data = new FileData()
  data.image = image;
  data.fileType = fileType;
  const uploadPromise = apigClient.invokeApi({}, '/users/upload', 'POST', {}, {image: image, fileType: fileType});


const observable = new Observable<FileReturnData>(observer => {

    uploadPromise.then(function (uploadResult) {
      console.log(uploadResult); // I see this in the console

      const fileReturnData = new FileReturnData();

      const responseBody = JSON.parse(uploadResult.body);

      fileReturnData.filename = responseBody.filename;
      console.log('IN OBSERVABLE');  //  I never get to this result
      observer.next(fileReturnData);
      observer.complete();


      return () => console.log('upload image user observable disposed');

    }).catch(function (uploadImageError) {

      return () => console.error(uploadImageError);
    });

  });

  return observable;

}
```

Comment: Most rxjs operators work on Promises the same way they do for Observables.  Instead of using the promise API, stick with combining observable streams (one just happens to be a promise).

Comment: Like use Observable.fromPromise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only use nested promises with Ajax calls like this but I believe your issue with your code, using observables and a nested promise is that you prematurely start the `invokeApi` http call, the call to `/users/upload` is not completing when you expect it to, thus subscribers of the observable returned by `upload` awaiting a observer.complete() will have unintended consequences because you are calling `observer.complete()` in `uploadPromise.then` which may have already completed or my not have completed yet.

See if this fixes your code:

```
  public upload(image, fileType): Observable<FileReturnData> {
      const apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
        accessKey: this.auth.cognitoAccessKey,
        secretKey: this.auth.cognitoSecretKey,
        sessionToken: this.auth.cognitoSessionToken,
        invokeUrl: this.auth.URL
      });

    const observable = new Observable<FileReturnData>(observer => {

        const data = new FileData()
        data.image = image;
        data.fileType = fileType;

        apigClient.invokeApi({}, '/users/upload', 'POST', {}, {image: image, fileType: fileType})
        .then(function (uploadResult) {
          console.log(uploadResult); // I see this in the console

          const fileReturnData = new FileReturnData();

          const responseBody = JSON.parse(uploadResult.body);

          fileReturnData.filename = responseBody.filename;
          console.log('IN OBSERVABLE');  //  I never get to this result
          observer.next(fileReturnData);
          observer.complete();

        }).catch(function (uploadImageError) {

          //handle error
        });

      });

      return observable;

    }
```

I personally find using nested promises for http calls easier to manage if I am understanding your scenario entirely. Here is a version of your code you can use, that uses promises only and then any Observable can call upload and await its completion:

```
  public upload(image, fileType): Promise<FileReturnData> {
      const apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
        accessKey: this.auth.cognitoAccessKey,
        secretKey: this.auth.cognitoSecretKey,
        sessionToken: this.auth.cognitoSessionToken,
        invokeUrl: this.auth.URL
      });



    const promise = new Promise<FileReturnData>((resolve, reject) => {

        const data = new FileData()
        data.image = image;
        data.fileType = fileType;
        //I moved this "invokeApi" call here because it does not seem like a factory method
        //it seems like you start an ajax call when "invokeApi" is called
        //so you must keep this all within the promise you are returning to callers
        //of the upload function
        apigClient.invokeApi({}, '/users/upload', 'POST', {}, {image: image, fileType: fileType})
        .then(uploadResult => {
          console.log(uploadResult); // I see this in the console

          const fileReturnData = new FileReturnData();

          const responseBody = JSON.parse(uploadResult.body);

          fileReturnData.filename = responseBody.filename;

          resolve(fileReturnData);

        }, msg => {
            reject(msg);
        }).catch(ex => {
          return () => console.error(ex);
        });

      });

      return promise;

    }
```

Comment: Your top example I think is close but It still is firing at different times. When I subscribe I don't get in the subscribe code block at all.

Comment: @user2385520 try using the second example and see if resolves reliably

Comment: @user2385520 in addition I just made a change to the top example, I removed those return => statements see what that does

Comment: The return statements were the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @user2385520 nice!